# I want to integrate ads from WordPress website to my ionic app, How do I do that?

Tags: ionic3

I am building an ionic app with WordPress API but I don't know how to make the ads displayed on my app

This is my html file.

```
<ion-content>
<div class="item-profile" text-center #profilePic [style.background- 
 image]="'url(' + item?.jetpack_featured_media_url + ')'">
  </div>
  <div class="item-detail" padding style=" z-index: 1119">
  <h1  [innerHTML]="item?.title.rendered"></h1>
  <h6>{{item?.date}}</h6>
  </div>  

    <div class="item-detail" padding>
    <span [innerHTML]="item?.content.rendered"></span>
    </div>
    </ion-content>
```

Here is the .ts file

```
    export class ItemDetailPage {
    item: any;
    getData:any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public api:Api, 
    navParams: NavParams, items: Items,public http: HttpClient) {
    var temp = navParams.get('itemName') || items.defaultItem;
     console.log(temp)
     this.getPOst(temp.id)
      }

      getPOst(id){
        this.api.get1('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' + id).subscribe(data=>{
       console.log(data)
        this.item = data
        })
         }
```

Comment: You can use firebase admob to show ads on your app as it will give you ads revenue from your web content.

Comment: is there any API from WordPress which will help me with this?

Comment: I don't think so that wordpress have any api for ads but still you can search on web.